# Insert value for items in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have already created a listview with the codes as below that displays apple, orange and banana. When I click on the item (Eg: apple) I want it to be displayed in a different activity as a textview along with the value. Eg: apple = 40 cal. For now I do not have a database to store these values.

This is the code for the listview :

```
public class ViewMenuList extends ListActivity {

String[] food = { "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_list);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, food));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + food[position] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

Comment: What is the actual question then? Are you getting the value you want and don't know how to show it in the next `Activity`?

Comment: @codeMagic I don't know how to insert value in the item. Right now when I click on it, it just shows a toast message that I've clicked on it. I want to be able to display the item in a new activity together with an int value with it so I'm able to do calculations in the new activity.

Comment: Ok, well see my answer. It should help. As far as the `int` value, you can have a separate `int[]` array that holds that information or if you store the information in a `static class` then you can access it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a couple different things then. You can simply pass the value using an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

```
   public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
   {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + food[position] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String name = food[position];
        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, NextActivityName.class);
        i.putExtra("foodName", name);
        startActivity(i);
   }
```

then retrieve it in the next `Activity` in `onCreate()`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String foodName = intent.getStringExtra("foodName");
```

Then call `setText(foodName)` on your `TextView` in the next `Activity`

You also could store the information in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) or in a `static` variable in a different class that would hold associated information with the food item.

Comment: What do I do if I want to display all three items in the next Activity?

Comment: You will need to pass all 3 in the `Intent` (either separately or as a `serializable`), add the array as a variable in the `Activity`, create a class to hold the array, or store them in a DB. It really depends on what you want to do with them

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry about it, we all have a lot to learn and we all had to start somewhere